# Difference between trapassato prossimo and passato prossimo

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, past-tense

What changes when I use trapassato or passato prossimo in the following phrases:

"Io ti **avevo avvisato**/**ho avvisato**, ma tu..."

and:

"- Ti ricordi la Melegatti?
- Sì, ha avuto un bambino un paio di anni fa.
- Infatti. La maternità l'**aveva/ha addolcita**..."

On my last language exchange the Italian native told me that I should use trapassato in both cases, but I don't see an explicit time precedence. She also noticed that in these examples passato prossimo sounds for her as something that happened now or recently, like a minute ago.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the context and, in your examples, on what follows. For instance, as regards Ms Melegatti: if that's the end of the conversation (implying that she is still *addolcita*), the *passato prossimo* is the only possible tense to be used. You'd use the *trapassato prossimo* if something like this followed:

– La maternità l'aveva addolcita, ma poi l'hanno licenziata e da allora è ridiventata scontrosa.

Even without a *ma poi...*, the phrasing with the trapassato seems to imply that she is no more so sweet.

As for the first example, see the difference between:

– Io ti avevo avvisato, ma tu hai fatto lo stesso di testa tua.

and

–Io ti ho avvisato: adesso fa' come credi.

So, you are perfectly right in assuming that [*trapassato prossimo*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/trapassato-prossimo_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) denotes “un evento compiuto prima di un altro evento del passato”. As for *passato prossimo*, that it “sounds ... as something that happened now or recently, like a minute ago” is a common misconception, even among many Italians (the other being that *passato prossimo* is more or less the only available past tense in Italian). It is instead used for any past event that has still effects on the present. You might say *nel 2008 Carla è partita per Londra*, meaning that she is still there. If your Italian is good enough, you can have a look [the article about it in the Enciclopedia dell'Italiano](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/passato-prossimo_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) and related articles on other tenses.